# Nignx 404エラーになる

Tags: nginx

CentOS7とNginx(1.14.0)で静的ページを表示させています。
root直下にある、`index.html`などは読み込まれるのですが、サブディレクトリ以降のファイルが読み込まれません。

具体的には、`ドメイン.com`にアクセスすると正常に表示されますが、`ドメイン.com/about`にアクセスするとnginxの404エラーになってしまうのです。

どのようにすれば、サブディレクトリ以降のファイルが読み込まれるでしょうか？
教えていただけると助かります。

nginx.confは以下のように設定しています。

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    root /var/www/html;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    # トップドメイン用の設定    
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/top.conf;

    # サブドメイン用の設定
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/サブドメイン名.conf;
```

トップドメイン用の設定`top.conf`は以下の通りに設定しています。

```
server {
    listen       80; 
    server_name  ドメイン.com;
    charset UTF-8;

    location / {
      root /var/www/html;
      index index.html index.html index.php;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        root           /var/www/html;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

サブドメイン用`サブドメイン名.conf`の設定

```
error_log  /var/www/サブドメイン用ディレクトリ名/current/log/nginx.error.log;
access_log /var/www/サブドメイン用ディレクトリ名/current/log/nginx.access.log;

client_max_body_size 2G;
upstream app_server {
  # 連携するunicornのソケットのパス
  server unix:/var/www/サブドメイン用ディレクトリ名/current/tmp/sockets/.unicorn.sock;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name  サブドメイン名.ドメイン.com;
  keepalive_timeout 5;
  root /var/www/サブドメイン用ディレクトリ名/current/public;

try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @app;
  location @app {
    # HTTP headers
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    #proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    proxy_pass http://app_server;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  location = /500.html {
    root /var/www/サブドメイン用ディレクトリ名/current/public;
  }
}
```

Comment: top.conf をコピーして /about/index.html を作成した上で `http://トップドメイン/about` にアクセスすると /about/ に 301 リダイレクト後、 /about/index.html が正常に表示されました。index.php を表示したいという意図でしょうか。

Comment: `index.html`を表示させたいです。
`top.conf`だけをコピーしてできたということは、他の設定が影響しているんでしょうか。

Comment: rewriteが効いてないっぽい気がしてきました。`/about`と`/about/`に対してアクセスした時のHTTPステータスが知りたいです（`curl -i`とかで見れます）。

Comment: `/about`と`/about/`どちらも「HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently」でした。

Comment: 怪しいですね。Locationヘッダの中にリダイレクト先があるのでそれも教えていただきたいです。

Comment: 結果が別れました。`/about`が`Location: https://ドメイン/about`となり、`/about/`がLocationの項目が表示されませんでした。

Comment: top.confを見る限りトップドメインはhttps設定がないので、`http://トップドメイン/about`は`https://トップドメイン/about`にリダイレクト後に404になっているものと思います。`/about/`がLocationなしっていうのは謎ですね。HTTPの仕様上、301にはLocation要素が必須とされているそうで（https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194988/）、Nginxがそれに反するレスポンスを返すのは、なにか良くないことが起きてる気がしますが、自分には原因が分かりません。

Comment: なるほど。わかりました。サーバを初期化して一からやってみることにします。ご回答ありがとうございました。

Answer (score -1):

サーバを一から再構築することにしました。